# if condition in a for loop in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am currently working on a for loop that shows your name score average and 
but i cant seem to make the grade appear.

#### Output

```
Enter Your Name:
Quiz 1
Quiz 2
Quiz 3
Average
Grade <- this one dont appear its on the if statement in my code
```

#### Code

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int nos[5][3]; //multi-dimention
    int r, c;
    char name[20];
    int x[3];
    int av=0;

    char l;

    do{
        system("cls");

        for(r=0; r<5; r++){ //Row
            cout<<"Enter Your Name : ";
            cin>>name;

            for(c=0; c<3; c++){ //Column
                cout<<"Enter Quiz "<<"["<<r<<"]"<<"["<<c<<"] : ";
                cin>>nos[r][c];

            }
            cout<<"Average : "<<(float)(nos[r][0]+nos[r][1]+nos[r][2])/3<<endl;
            av = ((float)nos[r][0]+nos[r][1]+nos[r][2])/3;
            if(av==0 && av<=74.99){
                cout<<"grade = 5.0"<<endl; }
            if(av ==75 && av<=76.99){
                cout<<"grade = 3.0"<<endl;  }
            if(av ==77 && av<=79.99){
                cout<<"grade = 2.75"<<endl;  }
            if(av ==80 && av<=82.99){
                cout<<"grade = 2.50"<<endl; }
            if(av ==83 && av<=84.99){
                cout<<"grade = 2.25"<<endl; }
            if(av ==85 && av<=87.99){
                cout<<"grade = 2.0"<<endl; }
            if(av ==88 && av<=90.99){
                cout<<"grade = 1.75"<<endl; }
            if(av ==91 && av<=93.99){
                cout<<"grade = 1.50"<<endl;}
            if(av ==94 && av<=96.99){
                cout<<"grade = 1.25"<<endl; }
            if(av ==97 && av<=100){
                cout<<"grade = 1.0"<<endl;}

        }

        cout<<"\nTry Another [Y/N] : ";
        cin>>l;
    } while(l!='N' && l!='n');
    getch();
}
```

Comment: use ranges as in `if( av>=0 && av<75 )` of use else if as in `else if(av<77)`

Answer (score 4):

You `if` conditions are wrong.
Either use an or (`||`) or set appropriate lower bounds.

For example:

```
if(av==0 && av<=74.99)
```

You should either say

```
if(av>=0 && av<=74.99)
```

or

```
if(av==0 || av<=74.99)
```

Depending on what your logic is (I guess the former).

Also, as correctly pointed out by Bill, you should be using `if else`s instead of all those `if`s. Even though they'd work in your case, `if else`s are preferred since they prevent logical errors. Better explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1796155/2302611
So your code (the conditions part) should look like:

```
if(av>=0 && av<=74.99){
    cout<<"grade = 5.0"<<endl; 
}
else if(av >=75 && av<=76.99){
    cout<<"grade = 3.0"<<endl;  
}       
else if(av >=77 && av<=79.99){
    cout<<"grade = 2.75"<<endl;  
}
else if(av >=80 && av<=82.99){
    cout<<"grade = 2.50"<<endl; 
}
else if(av >=83 && av<=84.99){
    cout<<"grade = 2.25"<<endl; 
}
else if(av >=85 && av<=87.99){
    cout<<"grade = 2.0"<<endl; 
}
else if(av >=88 && av<=90.99){
    cout<<"grade = 1.75"<<endl; 
}
else if(av >=91 && av<=93.99){
    cout<<"grade = 1.50"<<endl;
}
else if(av >=94 && av<=96.99){
    cout<<"grade = 1.25"<<endl; 
}
else if(av >=97 && av<=100){
    cout<<"grade = 1.0"<<endl;
}
else cout << "Grade not in bounds";
```

Comment: @BillLynch you're right. That's the way it should be. Though in the OP's case, there are no overlapping limits. I'll update my answer for correctness anyway.

Answer (score 1):

your if statement logic is the error, and int cannot be used to store floating point numbers, here are the code changes

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double nos[5][3]; //multi-dimention
    int r, c;
    char name[20];
    int x[3];
    double av = 0;

    char l;

    do{
        system("cls");

        for (r = 0; r<5; r++){ //Row
            cout << "Enter Your Name : ";
            cin >> name;

            for (c = 0; c<3; c++){ //Column                              
                cout << "Enter Quiz " << "[" << r << "]" << "[" << c << "] : ";
                cin >> nos[r][c];

            }
            av = (nos[r][0] + nos[r][1] + nos[r][2]) / 3;
            cout << "Average : " << av << endl;
            if (av >= 0 && av <= 74.99){
                cout << "grade = 5.0" << endl;
            }
            if (av >= 75 && av <= 76.99){
                cout << "grade = 3.0" << endl;
            }
            if (av >= 77 && av <= 79.99){
                cout << "grade = 2.75" << endl;
            }
            if (av >= 80 && av <= 82.99){
                cout << "grade = 2.50" << endl;
            }
            if (av >= 83 && av <= 84.99){
                cout << "grade = 2.25" << endl;
            }
            if (av >= 85 && av <= 87.99){
                cout << "grade = 2.0" << endl;
            }
            if (av >= 88 && av <= 90.99){
                cout << "grade = 1.75" << endl;
            }
            if (av >= 91 && av <= 93.99){
                cout << "grade = 1.50" << endl;
            }
            if (av >= 94 && av <= 96.99){
                cout << "grade = 1.25" << endl;
            }
            if (av >= 97 && av <= 100){
                cout << "grade = 1.0" << endl;
            }

        }

        cout << "\nTry Another [Y/N] : ";
        cin >> l;
    } while (l != 'N' && l != 'n');
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int nos[5][3]; //multi-dimention
    int r, c;
    char name[20];
    int x[3];
    int av=0;
    char l;
    do{
        system("cls");
        for(r=0; r<5; r++){ //Row
            cout<<"Enter Your Name : ";
            cin>>name;
            for(c=0; c<3; c++){ //Column
                cout<<"Enter Quiz "<<"["<<r<<"]"<<"["<<c<<"] : ";
                cin>>nos[r][c];
            }
            cout<<"Average : "<<(float)(nos[r][0]+nos[r][1]+nos[r][2])/3<<endl;
            av = ((float)nos[r][0]+nos[r][1]+nos[r][2])/3;
            if(av==0 || av<=74.99){
                cout<<"grade = 5.0"<<endl; }
            else if(av ==75 || av<=76.99){
                cout<<"grade = 3.0"<<endl;  }
            else if(av ==77 || av<=79.99){
                cout<<"grade = 2.75"<<endl;  }
            else if(av ==80 || av<=82.99){
                cout<<"grade = 2.50"<<endl; }
            else if(av ==83 || av<=84.99){
                cout<<"grade = 2.25"<<endl; }
            else if(av ==85 || av<=87.99){
                cout<<"grade = 2.0"<<endl; }
            else if(av ==88 || av<=90.99){
                cout<<"grade = 1.75"<<endl; }
            else if(av ==91 || av<=93.99){
                cout<<"grade = 1.50"<<endl;}
            else if(av ==94 || av<=96.99){
                cout<<"grade = 1.25"<<endl; }
            else(av ==97 || av<=100){
                cout<<"grade = 1.0"<<endl;}
        }
        cout<<"\nTry Another [Y/N] : ";
        cin>>l;
    } while(l!='N' && l!='n');
    getch();
}
```