# Redirecting HomePage

Tags: php, redirect

> Iam Learning PHP, so i have started an website..in that i have created index.php and index_1.php and login.php in which when user successful login the user has to be redirect to index.php but iam not getting it so i have created an another index_1.php in this page only three navigation bars will be there Home,projects and contactus.
>   This is my index.php Page

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
    <head>
  <title>Karthik</title>
<meta name="description" content="website description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <div id="logo_text">
      <!-- class="logo_colour", allows you to change the colour of the text -->
      <h1><a href="index.php">KarthikAenugula</a></h1>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">
      <!-- put class="selected" in the li tag for the selected page - to highlight which page you're on -->
      <li class="selected"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="project.php">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutme.php">AboutMe</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

> This is my index_1.php

```
   <?
 session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email']))
    {
   echo '<p>Please Login to continue <a href="login.php">Log In</a></p>';
   exit();
    }
   ?>


   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>

  <head>
  <title>Karthik</title>
  <meta name="description" content="website description" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
  <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style>
 .mySlides {display:none;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="main">
  <div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <div id="logo_text">
      <!-- class="logo_colour", allows you to change the colour of the text -->
      <h1><a href="index.php">KarthikAenugula</a></h1>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">
      <!-- put class="selected" in the li tag for the selected page - to highlight which page you're on -->
      <li class="selected"><a href="index_1.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="project1.php">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutme1.php">AboutMe</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact1.php">Contact</a></li>

                <?php 
                echo '<p align="right">'; 
                session_start();
                echo "Welcome";
                echo '<br>';
                  echo  ($_SESSION ['user_email']); 
                    echo '<br> Logout?<a href="logout.php">ClickHere</a></p>';
                  ?>
```

> This is my login.php

```
  <?php

 ob_start();

session_start();

if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
   {
  $user_email=$_POST['user_email'];
  $user_password=md5($_POST['user_password']);
  $con=@mysql_connect('localhost','xxxxx','xxxx') or                     die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('suryapra_aenugula_karthik');
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_registration where user_email='".$user_email."' AND user_password='".$user_password."'") or die("error in selection");
 $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
    {
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
     {
    $dbusername=$row['user_email'];
    $dbpassword=$row['user_password'];
    }
 if($user_email==$dbusername && $user_password==$dbpassword)
     {
 if(isset($_POST['remember']))
   {
setcookie('user_email',$user_email,time()+60*60*7);
setcookie('user_password',$user_email,time()+60*60*7);
}
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_email']=$user_email;
header("Location: index_1.php");
ob_end_flush();
    }
  }
    else
   {    
header("Location: login_2.php");
            ob_end_flush();

 }
 }
 else
{
   header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

> what my problem is if user logins he is redirecting to index.php and again login and register links are also getting in index.php
>   i want solution in which when user logins he should be redirect to index.php and login,register tabs should not be visible to him unless he presses logout button

Comment: Before you continue with anything else, you should address a couple of major issues: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [**Prepared Statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Another big one: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's _very_ insecure since many years back. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5, you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: pls tidy up the indentation also :(

Comment: what you said is correct but iam in initial stage and i will update my code to mysqli or PDO

Comment: ...and please.. **don't store the password in plaintext in a user cookie!**. When dealing with username and passwords, it's your _duty_ to read up on security best practices.

Comment: ok thanks bro iam getting some more programming skills from you... @Magnus Eriksson

Comment: No, you should do it correctly _from the start_. Not only will that save you time after the fact, but the sad reality is, you won't go back and refactor all these things later on. Plus, you will need to totally rewrite your code.

Comment: you are not create two different html page only check in menu if session is set then show only home , product, about us and contact if not then show all menus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic flow of User Authentication:

- User submits login form to `login.php` this, if login is correct, will set a `$_SESSION` variable to signal user is logged in.
- User is then redirected back to site, where
- In the templates, anything that is optional for loggedin/logged out users are wrapped in `IF` blocks

Something like so:

```
     <?php
     $logged_in = $_SESSION['logged_in'];
     ?>

     <nav>
         <?php if (!$logged_in):?>
             <a href="login-form.php">Login</a>
         <?php endif;?>
         <?php if ($logged_in):?>
             <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
         <?php endif;?>
     </nav>
```

Comment: Why not use a `if/else` instead if two `if`'s?

Comment: You could do. I tend not to, just so that chunks of "php/html" can be cut and paste at will... its less order dependant. If you wanted to put a link inbetween "login" and "logout", or move them around the page for example

Comment: If you like performance, you should use `if/else` when ever possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796100/what-is-faster-many-ifs-or-else-if - If you all of the sudden want to change order of things, change it then. Writing less readable code with worse performance for "maybe someday someone might..." isn't a good way of doing it.

Comment: LOL... this level of optimization is irrelevant at this level. In order the importance of php templates should be 1. Readability 2. Maintenance 3. Portability... The efficiency of saving a few clock cycles comes 2nd to developer productivity. Also the php parser is garbage, so i'm sceptical how "efficient" you can make it :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all after a successful login on the login page redirect user on the index.php page. 
you dont need index_2.php page.

After that edit your index page with following code where first we will check if [user_email] session is been created or not when we logged in if it is created we are not echoing anything if not then we will echo the login and register link. bellow is your new index.php page

```
<?php session_start();

 ?> 
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
    <head>
  <title>Karthik</title>
<meta name="description" content="website description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <div id="logo_text">
      <!-- class="logo_colour", allows you to change the colour of the text -->
      <h1><a href="index.php">KarthikAenugula</a></h1>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">
      <!-- put class="selected" in the li tag for the selected page - to highlight which page you're on -->
      <li class="selected"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="project.php">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutme.php">AboutMe</a></li>
      <?php if(isset($_SESSION[user_email]))
      {

      }
      else
      {
       echo "<li><a href='login.php'>Login</a></li>";
       echo "<li><a href='register.php'>Register</a></li>";
      }

      ?>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sry bro its not working..when user logins it again showing login and register tabs